# If using JSP include has same file names as other JSP 's , does not include the correct JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I have a web application that has

```
Index.jsp 
Include folder -> Menu.jsp
Admin folder  -> AdminIndex.jsp and other JSP 's
Admin/Include/ folder- >Menu.jsp
The AdminIndex.jsp is given below.

<%@ taglib prefix="str" uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/string-1.1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="/WEB-INF/spring.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="/WEB-INF/fmt.tld" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <%@ page language="java"%>

        <link href="theme/stylesheet-v1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script language=JavaScript src="JSFiles/scripts-rst.js"></script>
        <script language=JavaScript src="JSFiles/mm_menu.js"></script>
        <title>Administration - Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <jsp:include page="../include/Banner.jsp" />
        <jsp:include page="include/AdminHeaderHome.jsp" />
        <jsp:include page="include/Menu.jsp" />
        <jsp:include page="include/CenterAdminIndex.jsp" />
        <jsp:include page="../include/Footer.jsp" />

    </body>
</html>
```

This JSP was not able to show lefthand navigation  in Admin page becuase it was calling Menu.jsp in the root include folder which was navigation for index.jsp.
I figured this out by putting break points in the calling JSP and the Admin page was calling the Menu.jsp in the root include folder. so eventually I figured that file is opening a jsp in root include for Menu.jsp include and not in Admin/include folder.
I verified this when I changed include jsp to 
 and everything else started working.

This worked in older versions of spring jstl. For spring 3.1 I am going to have to modify all the jsp's in the Admin folder as they are not showing the navigation side bar.

Why is this happening? Does JSP no longer support same naming JSP's in sub folders? Somehow it seems the server is not able to interpret two different paths if the JSP names are same.

Comment: `<jsp:include page="../include/Banner.jsp" />`? You can't include files from outside the app context. I think this should just be `<jsp:include page="Banner.jsp" />`

Comment: <jsp:include page="../include/Banner.jsp" /> worked fine .. Its the Menu.jsp include that causes issues. It has to renamed to MenuAdmin.jsp otherwise the other Menu.jsp in root gets picked up. This worked before I migrated to spring 3.1 worked in spring 2.x